# SCOM: Override all monitors for host

Tags: scom

I'm running SCOM 2007 R2 to monitor both production and dev environments. I want all of the monitors to be enabled, but I want a way to disable all of the alerts on the dev servers. I know I can go in and manually override all of the monitors to disable the alerts, but there are about 30 monitors for each server. Is there a way I can just override all of the monitors for a single host at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to disable the alerting or the monitoring (or both)?

You could put the Dev servers into Maintenance Mode but I think this would probably also stop the monitoring (which means you wouldn't have any data recorded for the duration of the maintenance).

If it's just the alerts that are hassling you, you could put your servers into groups and change your alert subscriptions to exclude all servers that are in the Dev group.

Comment: +1 for distinction between alerting and monitoring. Maintenance mode causes the agent to stop sending monitoring data back altogether, including performance counters.

Answer (score 0):

While putting the dev servers into their own group would probably work, I just made a new alert view that only shows the active alerts from the prod servers. I also made a similar view for just the dev servers.

I'm still getting alerts from the dev servers, but now I don't have to see them if I don't want to.